# I want to use my PC WIred Internet Connected with my Tablet as Gateway

Tags: networking, usb

Hello I want to use my PC Wired Connected with Internet with my Tablet using a USB Conection. 
Is this possible ?
I have a PC COnnected with a ADSL with  4 Hubs. I want to at least use the  USB Cable provided   to Sync with my PC to be used as a Gateway to download apps and Connect with Internet. 
Thanks in advance,

Jose Q

Answer (score 1):

So what you're trying to do is called reverse tethering. This is quite the involved setup and you need to edit a few things on your tablet. I have only heard of this working on Android devices that are rooted, so depending on what type of configuration you have, it may not be possible.

Here is an XDA Developers forum on how to reverse tether on android devices (REQUIRES ROOT):
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494

Here is a guide for reverse tethering on iOS devices (Does not require Jailbreak): http://modgadgets.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1900